# Is Grafana used for analyzing system metrics alone?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, datasource, influxdb, grafana

I am new to grafana. I want to know whether grafana is used for only monitoring system metrics?
1) If not so, I am having postgreSQL database with some  live data in it. Can i use the grafana for accessing those postgres tables directly into grafana without any conversion like json.
2) If there is possibility to directly access postgres databse into grafana which data source can i use?

Please correct me if I am wrong..

Answer (score 3):

Grafana can be used to visualize any time-series or metrics and not just system metrics.

PostgreSQL can be used using a datasource plugin - https://github.com/sraoss/grafana-sqldb-datasource (haven't tried it out myself)

And there's a generic SQL Datasource being developed as well. Here's the PR for your reference. - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/5364

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know whether grafana is used for only monitoring system
>   metrics?

You can use grafana to display a lot of different metrics. I for example use grafana + influxdb to display different sensor values from my apartment.

> Can i use the grafana for accessing those postgres tables directly into grafana

I am not sure about that. But if you take a look at the available data-sources [LINK](https://grafana.net/plugins) you will see that there is no PostgreSQL. So I think this is a no.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried using grafana+graphite. But by default graphite generates the system metrics only. So as per your suggestion, If i installed influxdb how can i get the sensor values into it.?

Comment: If you use graphite check this out: http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/graphite/